# react-router url change but had to double click "Link" component for ui to change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

When loading for the first time the content is displayed correctly, clicking a link will change the URL but the view still the same. I had to click twice for the view to change.

**My router**

```
render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/:courseName/**" component={components.app}>
            <IndexRoute components={{
                sidebar: containers.sidebar,
                chapter: containers.chapter
            }} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**My dispatch inside the chapter component**

```
componentWillUpdate() {
    const { dispatch, params: { courseName, splat } }  = this.props;
    dispatch(actions.fetchChapter(courseName, splat));
```

Comment: That's it because you're working with the "old" props. Try to use the newest ones with something like this.`componentWillUpdate(props) {
    const { dispatch, params: { courseName, splat } }  = props;
    dispatch(actions.fetchChapter(courseName, splat));`

Comment: Thank you @dlopez!

Answer (score 0):

As @dlopez pointed out, I had to use the incoming props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("In erhe");
    const { dispatch, params: { courseName, splat } }  = nextProps;
    dispatch(actions.fetchChapter(courseName, splat));
}
```